create and use python venv from cmake
we are using cmake and invoking some python packages (like conan) from cmake.
However latest python 3.12 seams to enforce using venv.
I did some searching and found this interesting article
https://discourse.cmake.org/t/possible-to-create-a-python-virtual-env-from-cmake-and-then-find-it-with-findpython3/1132
I managed to install the requirements inside the venv but find_program is failing.
This is my cmake code
macro(create_venv)
  find_package(Python3 3.9 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
  set(SYSTEM_PYTHON_EXE_PATH ${Python3_EXECUTABLE})
  message(STATUS "+++++++++++++++++  Found system python located at ${SYSTEM_PYTHON_EXE_PATH}++++++++++++++++")
  # Taken from https://discourse.cmake.org/t/possible-to-create-a-python-virtual-env-from-cmake-and-then-find-it-with-findpython3/1132
  execute_process(COMMAND "${Python3_EXECUTABLE}" -m venv "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/venv" --upgrade-deps COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY)

  # Here is the trick update the environment with VIRTUAL_ENV variable (mimic the activate script)
  set(VENV_PATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/venv")
  set(ENV{VIRTUAL_ENV} "${VENV_PATH}")

  #[[
  enabling this line will enforce conan to use all packages from the venv cache (which is empty when newly created)
  this means every time you clean your cmake cache all 3rd parties will be recompiled or downloaded which will increase configure time
  You should comment in this line when playing around with conan config to not break your local build
  ]]
  # set (ENV{CONAN_USER_HOME} "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/conan") change the context of the search
  set(Python3_FIND_VIRTUALENV FIRST)
  # unset Python3_EXECUTABLE because it is also an input variable (see documentation, Artifacts Specification section)
  unset(Python3_EXECUTABLE)
  # Launch a new search
  find_package(Python3 3.9 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
  message(STATUS "+++++++++++++++++  Found venv python located at ${Python3_EXECUTABLE}++++++++++++++++")
  if(SYSTEM_PYTHON_EXE_PATH STREQUAL Python3_EXECUTABLE)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Python3 executable is the same as the system one, this is not expected")
  endif()


  # taken from https://www.scivision.dev/cmake-install-python-package/
  set(REQUIREMENTS_ARG "-r ${TOOLBOX_SOURCE_DIR}/python3/requirements_generic.txt")
  message(STATUS "Trying to install deps")
  execute_process(
    COMMAND "${Python3_EXECUTABLE}" -m pip install -r "${TOOLBOX_SOURCE_DIR}/python3/requirements_win32.txt" COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY
  )

  find_program(CONAN_CMD conan REQUIRED)
  if(NOT CONAN_CMD)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Conan executable not found! Please install conan.")
  endif()

endmacro()

This results in Could not find CONAN_CMD using the following names: conan
Do you know what is the issue here?

Your error message shows it is not finding "conan" at runtime, so we can deduce it's either a problem with the conan install, permissions, or environment variables not being set-up right (Depending on your OS).
Here's a solution:
Run pip list --verbose to find where Conan is installed.
For example, if it’s installed to C:/Users/ExampleUser/AppData/Local/Python/Python38/site-packages, you should be able to find conan.exe in C:/Users/MAEDEH/AppData/Local/Python/Scripts.
You need to add the given path/directory to your environment variables.
However, it is not recommended to install command line tools with pip.
It's recommended to set up pipx and do pipx install conan instead, which would put conan.exe into your environment variables automatically (an alternative to pipx is Conda which I prefer).

Hey Pedro, thx for your answer execute_process(   COMMAND "${Python3_EXECUTABLE}" -m pip list --verbose COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY ) properly points to C:/.../build/venv/Lib/site-packages => so all site packages are installed in the correct place. I will have a look at find_program if i could provide any paths hints. Does pipx support a requrements.txt? This does not seam to work in my case
